# Hash table mapping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hashtable

I have a large dataset with millions of rows of data. One of the data columns is ID.

I also have another (hash)table that maps the range of indices to a specific group that meets a certain criteria.

What is an efficient way to map the range of indices to include them as an additional column on my dataset in pandas?

As an example, lets say that the dataset looks like this:

```
In [18]:
print(df_test)

Out [19]:
    ID
0   13
1   14
2   15
3   16
4   17
5   18
6   19
7   20
8   21
9   22
10  23
11  24
12  25
13  26
14  27
15  28
16  29
17  30
18  31
19  32
```

Now the hash table with the range of indices looks like this:

```
In [20]:
print(df_hash)

Out [21]:
   ID_first
0         0
1         2
2        10
```

where the index specifies the group number that I need.

I tried doing something like this:

```
for index in range(df_hash.size):
    try:
        df_test.loc[df_hash.ID_first[index]:df_hash.ID_first[index + 1], 'Group'] = index
    except:
        df_test.loc[df_hash.ID_first[index]:, 'Group'] = index
```

Which works well, except that it is really slow as it loops over the length of the hash table dataframe (hundreds of thousands of rows). It produces the following answer (which I want):

```
In [23]:
print(df_test)

Out [24]:
    ID  Group
0   13    0
1   14    0
2   15    1
3   16    1
4   17    1
5   18    1
6   19    1
7   20    1
8   21    1
9   22    1
10  23    2
11  24    2
12  25    2
13  26    2
14  27    2
15  28    2
16  29    2
17  30    2
18  31    2
19  32    2
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Would this work? [Replace values in column of Pandas DataFrame using a Series lookup table
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876121/1609514)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map` the index of df_test using ID_first to the index of df_hash, and then `ffill`. Need to construct a Series as the pd.Index class doesn't have a ffill method.

```
df_test['group'] = (pd.Series(df_test.index.map(dict(zip(df_hash.ID_first, df_hash.index))), 
                              index=df_test.index)
                      .ffill(downcast='infer'))

#    ID  group
#0   13      0
#1   14      0
#2   15      1
#...
#9   22      1
#10  23      2
#...
#17  30      2
#18  31      2
#19  32      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, what I need is to group by index, not ID. I have edited the question to reflect this. Is it possible to implement something similar with indices?

Comment: Fantastic! It works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

you can do [`series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
df_test['group'] = df_test['ID'].isin(df_hash['ID_first']).cumsum() #.sub(1)
```

---

```
print(df_test)

    ID  group
0    0      1
1    1      1
2    2      2
3    3      2
4    4      2
5    5      2
6    6      2
7    7      2
8    8      2
9    9      2
10  10      3
11  11      3
12  12      3
13  13      3
14  14      3
15  15      3
16  16      3
17  17      3
18  18      3
19  19      3
```

Comment: This is super cool! However, what I need is to group by index, not ID. I have edited the question to reflect this. Is it possible to implement something similar with indices? Thanks!